# wx.PopupWindow without calling Frame

Tags: python-2.7, popup, wxpython

I've searched around and all the wx.Popupwindow requires the frame to be setup. Is it possible to create a pop window in wx without using frame to launch it?

Because I just need the Popup Window excluding the frame to show up.